# Making a http request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xmlhttprequest

I'd like to make a get request like below, on my React App with or without Axios. But I don't know how to add my auth token for that.

```
curl -X GET https://server.url/acp-service/sites -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'X-Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJ...long.string.here'
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Using [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```
(async () => {
  const rawResponse = await fetch(' https://server.url/acp-service/sites', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-Authorization': 'your_auth_string'
    }
  });
  const content = await rawResponse.json();

  console.log(content);
})();
```

Comment: Why "Using fetch()" when the question is tagged [tag:xmlhttprequest]?!